How to Display Decimal Values with 3 Decimal Places in Athena Table from Integer JSON Data Stored in S3?
I have JSON data stored in an S3 bucket, and I'm creating an Athena table to query this data. One of the columns in the JSON represents monetary values stored as integers (e.g., 1000 represents $10.00). I need to display these values in my Athena table with three decimal places (e.g., 1000 should be displayed as $10.000). Is there a way to achieve this directly in the DDL (Data Definition Language) when creating the Athena table, perhaps by dividing the integer values by 100? Any insights or examples would be greatly appreciated.
i tried it with decimal data type of athena like decimal(4,2) but it add .00 to the end of every integer

This might help.
SELECT  concat ('$' , regexp_replace ( format('%,.0f', 10000 + 0.0), ',','.' ) ) as val ;

==========>
1 $10.000


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
